# The view 'Index' was not found, хотя вызываю другой метод

Tags: c#, .net, mvc

В постмене отправляю запрос `https://localhost:5001/Comparsion/AddProductToComparsionList` и мне говорит: *The view 'Index' was not found*. Подскажите, почему не находит индекс и вообще, почему он вызывается? Я-же не индекс, а другой метод вызываю.

```
public class ProductComparsion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }
}

public class ProductComparsionVM
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public List<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }
}

public class MapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        this.CreateMap<ProductComparsion, ProductComparsionVM, ProductComparsionEVM>();
    }
}

public class ComparsionController : CmsController
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IInternalMapper _mapper;

    public ComparsionController(IInternalMapper mapper, AppDbContext dbContext) : base(serviceProvider)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _productRepo = productRepo;
        _userManager = (CmsUserManager<AppUser>)userManager;
    }
    // Error
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string code)
    {
        var productComparsion = await _dbContext.ProductsComparsion
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();
        var vm = _mapper.Map<IReadOnlyCollection<ProductComparsionVM>>(productComparsion);

        return View(vm);
    }
    // Я вызываю это, а вызывается индекс
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddProductToComparsionList([FromBody] List<int> productIds, int categoryId, int? listId)
    {
        return Json(await _productRepo.AddProductToComparsionList(productIds, categoryId, listId));
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте перед классом ComparsionController поставить аттрибут [ApiController]. Не совсем понятно откуда вы взяли CmsController, api наследовать надо от ControllerBase

Comment: @DennisSpade С ним выдает ошибку: Action 'Bs.WebApp.Controllers.ComparsionController.Index (Bs.WebApp)' does not have an attribute route. Action methods on controllers annotated with ApiControllerAttribute must be attribute routed

Comment: CmsController наследуется от ControllerBase

Comment: Смотрите, вы в одном контроллере смешали разные вещи. Через постман вы хотите получить ответ от апи ендпойнта, через индекс - вернуть UI представление. Как по мне - это должны быть разные приложения, но можно сделать разные контроллеры просто.

Comment: Для примера - закомментируйте ваш Index  и попробуйте получить ответ от апи

Comment: И да, надо добавть аттрибут route к  AddProductToComparsionList(после [HttpPost]) - например: [Route("AddProductToComparsionList")]

Comment: @DennisSpade Спасибо, удалил индекс и теперь все находит. Но теперь из постмена не подтягиваются параметры почему-то. Добавил скриншот

Comment: Смотрите, у вас [FromBody] относится только к первому параметру (productIds), остальные параметры (categoryId, listId) идут без атрибута. Соответственно система пытается перевести то что вы задали в body postmanа к типу List<int>

Comment: Я вам советую создать модель(класс), к которой будет привязываться body.

Comment: @DennisSpade Хорошо, спасибо